# PostgreSQL server getting stopped frequently

Tags: .net, postgresql, azure

I have installed postgreSQL on a Virtual Machine of Azure after some times postgres server getting stopped and showing message and while trying to refresh then show me error 'server stopped abnormally please reconnect'

Please help me is any setting in postgres?

[image]

Comment: please show server error, not client?..

Comment: Please check attached image

Comment: you attached image is pgadmin - a client. but yeah probably it's just network problem or some restriction on duration... If you dont have access to server - guesses are all that left

Comment: Ok Thanks Vao, this is my PG admin where I have created my database . and I am using my Azure Virtual Machine public IP to connect from outside to  VM postgres

Comment: I have tried with setting Keep-Alive in postgres Config file but not working
tcp_keepalives_idle